# ExtendScript: How to add InDesign DOM to ExtendScript Object Model Viewer?

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have just started with Adobe InDesign scripting.

I saw at another developer's windows system - he would click on Help->Object Model Viewer (Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit) and there were multiple object models listed and he could select inDesign DOM from there.

I just installed InDesign CS6 and my ESTK object model viewer shows only 3 models - 
i) Core JS classes
ii) scriptUI classes
iii) adobe bridge c6 object model

How can I add InDesign DOM to the list?

Comment: If you run this script: `#target indesign` and on a new line `alert(app.name);`
does InDesign launch and the Object Model gets updated ? (should see some changes in the Data Browser Panel)

Comment: It says - "indesign" is undefined!

Comment: hmmm...couldn't find a super straight forward way to let ESTK know you've got Indesign installed. Can you try to install [another version](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scripting/estk.html) and hopefully the installer will figure out what adobe products you have available. The latest version to download is 3.5 while CS6 ships with 3.8 but hopefully there won't be crucial changes between the versions

Comment: any joy with the other version of ESTK ?

Comment: Have been working my a## off. Didn't get the time to install the other  version, i'll do that tomorrow and update here!
People at adobe forums want me to re-install too. I hope it does work.

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Comment: Windows 7. I have CS6 products but ESTK doesn't want to recognize any products in the suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a new file named `connect_to_estk.jsx` with the following contents:

```js
$.writeln("Connected to " + app.name + " " + app.version);
```

Then move the file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS6\Scripts\Scripts Panel` or similar.

Next open InDesign and hit Ctrl+Alt+F11 to show the Scripts panel. (Or select Window > Utilities > Scripts.)

In the Scripts panel, expand the Application panel, right-click on connect_to_estk.jsx, and select "Run Script".

The ESTK window will now open if it wasn't open already. The "JavaScript Console" pane in the ESTK will say something like `Connected to Adobe InDesign 8.0.0.370`.

In ESTK, select File > New. Expand the drop-down menu in the top-left corner. There should be an entry for InDesign. Select it. The link on the left should be green. If not, click it.

Finally, open the Object Model Viewer. The Indesign DOM should now be in the drop-down menu.

Comment: This doesn't work too!
I give up, I'll use Jongware! Thanks for the help anyway mate.

Answer (score 0):

Choose InDesign from the target dropdown and press the red connect button.
InDesign should create the object model xml file on first contact.
If that does not help, execute any script from within ESTK, e.g. $.writeln(app.name);

Comment: That's what the problem is. InDesign does not appear in the drop down list, and I don't really know how it can be added there.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I installed InDesign after having photoshop on the machine earlier.  InDesign never appeared in the dropdown until I ran a script with '#target indesign' at the top - then it would add it to the dropdown until I restarted the ESTK.